# R Generate a vector with increasing and then decreasing elements

Tags: r, vector

How do I generate a vector in the form

`1 2 ... 19 20 19 ... 2 1`

Is it possible using the `c()` function?

Comment: `c(1:20, 19:1)` or `c(1:20, rev(1:19))`?

Comment: This works! Write it as an answer so that I can upvote you.

Comment: Or you could just use maths: `20 - abs((-19):19)`

Comment: more general `n=20;c(1:n,(n-1):1)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `seq` as well as `rev` function for the desired purpose.

**seq**

```
> c(1:20, seq(19,1,-1))
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1
```

As suggested by @jimbou,

```
> c(1:20, 19:1)
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1
> c(1:20, rev(1:19))
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1
```